# Consuming JSON values using kafka connect json api in kafka streams : JAVA

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to consume a json message using kafka connect api in kafka streams.
I tried searching in google but i could not find any substantial information on how to read json message in streams api.

Therefore, with the limited knowledge i have tried the below method.

```
package com.kafka.api.serializers.json;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ForeachAction;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ConsumerUtilities {

    private static ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    public static Properties getProperties() {

        Properties configs = new Properties();
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
                "Kafka test application");
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer");
        return configs;
    }

    public static KStreamBuilder getStreamingConsumer() {
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        return builder;
    }

    public static void printStreamData() {
        KStreamBuilder builder = getStreamingConsumer();
        KStream<String, JsonNode> kStream = builder.stream("test");
        kStream.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, JsonNode>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(String key, JsonNode value) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(key + " : " + om.treeToValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, getProperties());
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }

}

package com.kafka.api.serializers.json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerUtilities {

    private static ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();


    public static org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, JsonNode> getProducer() {
        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
                "kafka json producer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "localhost:9092");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer");

        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, JsonNode> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, JsonNode>(
                configProperties);
        return producer;
    }

    public ProducerRecord<String,JsonNode> createRecord(Person person){
        JsonNode jsonNode = om.valueToTree(person);
        ProducerRecord<String,JsonNode> record = new ProducerRecord<String,JsonNode>("test",jsonNode);
        return record;
    }

}
```

When i execute the code i am getting exception as below

```
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener for group Kafka test application failed on partition assignment
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to configure value serde class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:770)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.<init>(AbstractProcessorContext.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.<init>(ProcessorContextImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:255)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:1147)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$800(StreamThread.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:457)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:764)
    ... 19 more
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN.
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] Stream thread shutdown complete
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD.
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29] All stream threads have died. The Kafka Streams instance will be in an error state and should be closed.
[Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR.
Exception in thread "Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [Kafka test application-d3a307c9-d998-421f-829c-85532efc8b29-StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:543)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:457)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to configure value serde class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:770)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.<init>(AbstractProcessorContext.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.<init>(ProcessorContextImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:255)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:1147)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$800(StreamThread.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:536)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:764)
    ... 19 more
```

I am looking for some guidance to solve the issue.

Created custom serializer and deserializer as per Matthias suggestion

```
package com.kafka.api.utilities;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ForeachAction;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;

import com.kafka.api.models.Person;
import com.kafka.api.serdes.JsonDeserializer;
import com.kafka.api.serdes.JsonSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;

public class ConsumerUtilities {

    //private static ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    public static Properties getProperties() {

        Properties configs = new Properties();
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
                "Kafka test application");
        configs.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
//      configs.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
//              "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
//      configs.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
//              "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer");
        return configs;
    }

    public static KStreamBuilder getStreamingConsumer() {
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        return builder;
    }

    public static void printStreamData() {
        JsonSerializer<Person> personJsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>();
        JsonDeserializer<Person> personJsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Person.class);
        Serde<Person> personSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(personJsonSerializer, personJsonDeserializer);

        KStreamBuilder builder = getStreamingConsumer();
        KStream<String, Person> kStream = builder.stream(Serdes.String(),personSerde , "test");
        kStream.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(String key, Person value) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + value.toString());
            }

        });

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, getProperties());
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }

}

package com.kafka.api.serdes;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T>{

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    private Class<T> type;

    /*
     * Default constructor needed by kafka
     */
    public JsonDeserializer(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean arg1) {
        if(type == null){
            type = (Class<T>) map.get("type");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String undefined, byte[] bytes) {
        if(bytes == null || bytes.length == 0){
            return null;
        }

        try{
            return om.readValue(bytes, type);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new SerializationException(e);
        }
    }

    protected Class<T> getType(){
        return type;
    }

}

package com.kafka.api.serdes;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> config, boolean isKey) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            return om.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException();
        }
    }

}
```

Exception: After executing the streaming application i am getting the below exception. I am confused.

```
[Kafka test application-cee84455-78ca-4a2f-881a-89b3c3a00e4b-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [Kafka test application-cee84455-78ca-4a2f-881a-89b3c3a00e4b] State transition from RUNNING to ERROR.
Exception in thread "Kafka test application-cee84455-78ca-4a2f-881a-89b3c3a00e4b-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize value for record. topic=test, partition=0, offset=0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:46)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:457)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@5ee179dc; line: 1, column: 11]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@5ee179dc; line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3524)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2686)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:878)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
    at com.kafka.api.serdes.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:43)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:512)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:457)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams API needs to read and write data, and thus, it used the abstraction of a `Serde` that is a wrapper for a serializer and deserializer at the same time. This is what the exception basically says.

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde

Thus, you need to wrap `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserialzier` into a `JsonSerde` and use this `JsonSerde` in `StreamsConfig`.

The simplest way to do this, is to use `Serdes.serdeFrom(...)` method (note: `Serdes` -- plural). As an alternative, you can also implement `Serde` interface (note `Serde` -- singular) directly. You can find examples in `Serdes` class on how to implement `Serde` interface.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have created serializer and deserializer and wrapped. But i am getting the above exception. Please help.

Comment: The exception comes from your deserializer. I guess you need to debug this part by yourself -- it's not a Streams issue... You can see from the stack trace, that your deserializer is called... Seems like a schema issue?

Comment: This answer is not helping please add any code how You have used JsonSerde or any example

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java